# Is this a secure and efficient way to access a json property with AngularJS?

Tags: json, security, angularjs

I'm starting on AngularJS and I'd like to show this code that is accessing a route parameter's property.. Is it safe/best practice to do it this way?

```
angular.module('messagecat', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/messages', {templateUrl: '/bundles/acmestore/js/partials/messages-list.html',   controller: MessagesListCtrl}).
      when('/messages/:messageId', {templateUrl: '/bundles/acmestore/js/partials/message-detail.html', controller: MessageDetailCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/messages'});
}]);

/*controller*/

function MessagesListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/messages').success(function(data) {
    $scope.messages = data;
  });
}

/* Does this following bit seem reasonable to you?*/
function MessageDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $http.get('/messages').success(function(data) {
    $scope.messages = data[$routeParams.messageId];
    //console.log($scope.messages);
  });
}

the json model: 

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "iam": 1,
        "youare": 2,
        "lat": 50.8275853,
        "lng": 4.3809764,
        "msgbody": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
    }
]
```

Comment: What concerns do you have about it?  Looks fine to me.  I'm suprised, though, that the server doesn't allow you to messages by id, that you'd have to pull down all of them when you just want one.

Comment: My concern is I am passing the path stuff inside my code without really sanitizing th.. what if someone puts malicious stuff as a url... You mean I should have a separate back-end api for a single message? (I am doing the backend myself and as I'm a front-end dev...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot trust anything you have delivered to the client since it's all accessible to the user, after all, they can just press f12 to bring up the same development tools. In the end you have to focus on the Web API the data is being sent from. It has to be secure (the user must be authenticated and authorized for each operation) and validate everything sent to it thoroughly... Put another way, code the Web API as though it's being called from anywhere!

Comment: "code the Web API as though it's being called from anywhere!" +100 !